python google cloud DLP TransformationErrorHandling example
Hi I am looking for example for:
google cloud DLP TransformationErrorHandling implementation in Python, I have not found an example anywhere. I am am using dlp_v2, here is some of my code
        # deidentify_config = {
        #         "transformationErrorHandling": {
        #             "leaveUntransformed": {
        #
        #             }
        #         }
        #     }

        deidentify_config = dlp_v2.types.DeidentifyConfig(
            dlp_v2.types.TransformationErrorHandling(
                dlp_v2.types.TransformationErrorHandling.LeaveUntransformed
            )
        )



        # Create the deidentify request
        deidentify_request = dlp_v2.ReidentifyContentRequest(
            parent=f"projects/{project_id}/locations/northamerica-northeast1",
            reidentify_template_name=template_id,
            item=item,
            reidentify_config = deidentify_config

        )

I tried so many things and it does not work. Appreciate the help.
        # deidentify_config = {
        #         "transformationErrorHandling": {
        #             "leaveUntransformed": {
        #
        #             }
        #         }
        #     }

        deidentify_config = dlp_v2.types.DeidentifyConfig(
            dlp_v2.types.TransformationErrorHandling(
                dlp_v2.types.TransformationErrorHandling.LeaveUntransformed
            )
        )



        # Create the deidentify request
        deidentify_request = dlp_v2.ReidentifyContentRequest(
            parent=f"projects/{project_id}/locations/northamerica-northeast1",
            reidentify_template_name=template_id,
            item=item,
            reidentify_config = deidentify_config

        )


What doesn't work?

The the library does not accept anything I pass to it, it says it expecta a dict object, and when I pass it that it says it has no attributes I gave example for.

https://cloud.google.com/sensitive-data-protection/docs/inspecting-text#dlp_inspect_string-python has an example of how to put together python requests.
In your example code you are providing many named parameters, but you should instead provide just one named parameter request (a dict), and set all the fields inside: parent, deidentify_config, etc.
Other references:

Guide to deid using JSON / command line: https://cloud.google.com/sensitive-data-protection/docs/inspect-sensitive-text-de-identify


I tried all of it, could you provide an example exactly how it might go for transformationErrorHandling
